# Interpreting a nuclear decay scheme

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

[image: Beta Minus decay for Iodine 133.]

From my understanding, this is a decay scheme that shows the percentage of each energy level at which the disintegrated mother nucleus has reached after the disintegration has occurred. But what do the other numbers and arrows show?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. Please edit the question to give credit to the author of the diagram. It's rude to cut and paste stuff on the internet without attribution. I've edited out some salutations, etc., which are discouraged on stackexchange.

Comment: It was from my notes. The professor did not give a source.

Comment: Then please edit the question to say that.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to find out the interpretation of this diagram would be for you to look at the source where you got the diagram. They should define their conventions somewhere. However, it's not too hard to figure out most of the labels if one understands the physics.

If you look at the third energy level as an example, 11/2- is the spin-parity, 164 is the excitation energy in keV, and 12 d is the lifetime (half-life or mean lifetime). On the left, 0.48% is the probability of populating this state in beta decay. I don't know what the italicized 9.7 is.

Looking at the gamma ray deexciting that level, 164 is the energy in keV, and M4 is the multipolarity. For the gammas hat have a light-face number to the left of the bold-face energy, I believe those are the intensities as a percentage of all beta decays.